# Fast reverse sort in (SWI) Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog

I'm looking for a fast way to sort a list in reverse order in Prolog. Algorithmically it should perform as quickly as standard sort, but the options that I've come up with are much slower, for obvious reasons.

Predicate `rsort1/2` sorts and then reverses.

```
rsort1(L1, L2) :-
    sort(L1, Tmp),
    reverse(Tmp, L2).
```

Predicate `rsort2/2` uses `predsort/3` with a custom comparator.

```
rsort2(L1, L2) :-
    predsort(reverse_compare, L1, L2).

reverse_compare(Delta, E1, E2) :-
    compare(Delta, E2, E1).
```

To test their performance I've generated a huge random list like this:

```
?- Size = 1234567,
   findall(N, (between(1, Size, _), N is random(Size)), Ns),
   assert(test_list(Ns)).
Size = 1234567,
Ns = [183677, 351963, 737135, 246842, 22754, 1176800, 1036258|...].
```

These are the runtimes for the standard `sort`:

```
?- test_list(Ns), time(sort(Ns, NsS)).
% 2 inferences, 7.550 CPU in 8.534 seconds (88% CPU, 0 Lips)
Ns = [183677, 351963, 737135, 246842, 22754, 1176800, 1036258, 625628|...],
NsS = [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16|...].
```

... for `rsort1`:

```
?- test_list(Ns), time(rsort1(Ns, NsS)).
% 779,895 inferences, 8.310 CPU in 9.011 seconds (92% CPU, 93850 Lips)
Ns = [183677, 351963, 737135, 246842, 22754, 1176800, 1036258, 625628|...],
NsS = [1234564, 1234563, 1234562, 1234558, 1234557, 1234556, 1234555|...].
```

... and for `rsort2`:

```
?- test_list(Ns), time(rsort2(Ns, NsS)).
% 92,768,484 inferences, 67.990 CPU in 97.666 seconds (70% CPU, 1364443 Lips)
Ns = [183677, 351963, 737135, 246842, 22754, 1176800, 1036258, 625628|...],
NsS = [1234564, 1234563, 1234562, 1234558, 1234557, 1234556, 1234555|...].
```

Can I do better than `rsort1` and `rsort2` speedwise?

Comment: Consider using different input for benchmarking. Many sort algorithms will do "best" when their input is "already in order" and "worst" when their input is in the opposite of the correct order, which may explain a big part of the difference you see with `rsort2`.

Comment: @aschepler thanks, I'm testing now on random input, it changes nothing though...

Comment: predsort/3 is slower because it's not a built-in (it's written in Prolog in SWI, while sort/2 and keysort/2 are written in C). Using keysort/2 is typically faster than predsort/3 but requires auxiliary (global) stack space for the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're after a sorting routine that is portable (i.e., defined using PROLOG), then you probably won't be able to implement anything faster (or as fast, with a need to reverse the sort order) than those predicates that execute sorting routines natively in C/C++, such as `sort/2` or `msort/2`.

If speed is of overriding concern here, you could of course write your own non-portable predicate with an external definition to do the reverse sorting. For example, the [SWI-PL C++ interface](http://bit.ly/aAqwNz) could be used (see the examples there) to write a C++ definition of `rsort/2`, perhaps using the [comparison predicates](http://bit.ly/9Qljba) also implemented in C++.

Similarly, you could also write `rsort/2` in C using the SWI-PL C interface. [`src/pl-list.c`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/pl-57x.git?a=blob;f=src/pl-list.c) in the SWI-PROLOG source contains implementations of the sorting methods (namely `nat_sort()`) which is used for `sort/2`, `msort/2` and `keysort/2`. To implement `rsort/2`, you might only need to follow their implementation and tweak/reverse the interpretation of calls to `compare()` which describes the standard order of terms.

Answer (score -1):

define predicates: 
1. get lowest number in a list. 
2. deleting an item in a list. 
3. merging two lists. 
4. sorting a list by 
a) getting the lowest 
b) deleting the lowest in a list 
c) sort the new list without the lowest (recursion) 
with the base rule orderlist([X],[X]).

Comment: That algorithm is quite inefficient. Quick-sort or merge-sort are easier to implement in prolog and much faster... though pure prolog versions are not going to beat the builtins.